# How do I position an image using Magick++?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I know this is a very simple question, but I have been simply unable to find an answer. As a workaround, I've been using `roll`, but this is not ideal. I would like to be able to move the contents of my images without them rolling over to the other side using the Magick++ libary (not `convert`!).

Comment: Use -distort SRT. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#srt. Sorry, I do not know the Magick++ equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Magick::Image.distort()` is the method you need --- as pointed out by fmw42 in the comments.

Here's an example using `-distort Affine`, but `SRT` would give you more control.

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>

int main() {
    Magick::Image img("wizard:");
    size_t numberOfArguments = 4;
    double * listOfArguments = new double[numberOfArguments];
    listOfArguments[0] = 0.0;
    listOfArguments[1] = 0.0;
    listOfArguments[2] = img.rows() / 4.0;
    listOfArguments[3] = img.columns() / 4.0;
    bool bestFit = Magick::MagickFalse;
    img.distort(Magick::AffineDistortion,
                numberOfArguments,
                listOfArguments,
                bestFit);
    img.write("output.png");
}
```

Remember that the number of arguments alter between distortion methods, and each method interprets the order of arguments differently based on argument count.

For example, with `SRT` the order would be mapped as ...

```
===============  ========================================
Total Arguments  Argument Order
---------------  ----------------------------------------
 1                Angle
 2                Scale, Angle
 3                X, Y, Angle
 4                X, Y, Scale, Angle
 5                X, Y, ScaleX, ScaleY, Angle
 6                X, Y, Scale, Angle, NewX, NewY
 7                X, Y, ScaleX, ScaleY, Angle, NewX, NewY
===============  ========================================
```